# On the bool type column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as follows,

```
import pandas as pd data = [[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["a", "b"])
```

To query row a == 2 and b == 20, the code

```
df[(df["a"]==2) & (df["b"]==20)]
```

works fine but

```
df[df["a"]==2 & df["b"]==20]
```

returns an error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Is there any underlying difference that results in this?

Comment: One word answer: precedence. In the first case because of parentheses, `&` is only evaluated finally. In the second case `&` takes precedence. `(2 & df["b"])` doesnt make any sense.